# Why is my code dropping the values when creating a dataframe out of a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

In my program, I am trying to create a dataframe which consists of users and a few pieces of information like Username, Role, Status, etc. I'm trying to create a blank list, then update it with pieces of information from various APIs. Once I have all the info inputted, the Dict is turned into a dataframe and which is then used elsewhere in the code.

However, it seems when I create a Dictionary, update the values, then create a Dataframe out of it, the values of each key are dropped. I want each key to be a column.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

SimpleDict = {
        "Username":[],
        'Role':[],
        'User Status':[],
        'laptop Status':[],
        'Laptop Serial':[],
        'Error':[]
    }
SimpleDict.update({'Username': 'Goose'})
SimpleDict.update({'User Status': 'Active'})
SimpleDict.update({'Role': 'CEO'})

print(SimpleDict)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(SimpleDict)

print(df)
```

Expected/Desired Output:

```
0 Username - Role - User Status - Laptop Status - Laptop Serial - Error
1 Goose    - CEO  - Active      -               -               -
```

Actual Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Username, Role, User Status, laptop Status, Laptop Serial, Error]
Index: []
```

Comment: Change to `SimpleDict.update({'Username': ['Goose']})`, and so on

Comment: why are you doing `SimpleDict.update({'Username': 'Goose'})`? Do you understand what that does? For starters, this is equivalent to `SimpleDict["Username"] = "Goose"`. The value is "dropped" because **you replaced that key with another value*

Comment: @inspectorG4dget This introduces a 'ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length' error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because I want to replace the blank value for key 'Username' with 'Goose'. The value seems to be dropped when creating a dataframe out of the dictionary.

Comment: @GooseAtCompany there is no blank value there, keys cannot have "blank values". The value of that key is a list object, an empty list. You replaced that value with another value, a string object. You probably meant to *append* to the list object at that key, not replace it

Comment: What you want is `SimpleDict["Username"].append("Goose")`

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dataframe with specified columns,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Username', 'Role', 'User Status', 'laptop Status', 'Laptop Serial', 'Error'])
```

**Method 1**

```
df.loc[0,['Username','Role','User Status']] = ['Goose', 'CEO', 'Active']
df
###
  Username Role User Status laptop Status Laptop Serial Error
0    Goose  CEO      Active           NaN           NaN   NaN
```

**Method 2**

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'Username':['Goose'], 'Role':['CEO'], 'User Status':['Active']})])
df
###
  Username Role User Status laptop Status Laptop Serial Error
0    Goose  CEO      Active           NaN           NaN   NaN
```

Note: `pandas.DataFrame.append()` is deprecated since pandas version 1.4.0